# PostgreSQL nested UDTs ans CAST syntax

Tags: postgresql, types, casting

I have few UD types:

```
CREATE TYPE SOME_TYPE AS (
    aaa INT,
    bbb TEXT
);
CREATE TYPE SOME_ANOTHER_TYPE AS (
    ccc int,
    ddd SOME_TYPE
);
CREATE TYPE SOME_ANOTHER_DAMNIT_TYPE AS (
    eee int,
    fff SOME_ANOTHER_TYPE
);
```

Okay, i can make first from SQL:

```
select '(123,blablabla)'::SOME_TYPE;
```

And i can make second:

```
select '(456, "(123,blablabla)")'::SOME_ANOTHER_TYPE;
```

But if i try to make third...

```
select '(789,"(456, "(123,blablabla)")")'::SOME_ANOTHER_DAMNIT_TYPE;
```

... pl throw error:

> [22P02] ERROR: malformed record literal: "(456, "(123  Подробности:
>
> Unexpected end of input.

**Question**: how to make third type without plpgsql? I need it for calling from jdbc, to transfer object. I know, i can 'flatten' this object, but i want transfer it 'as is'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have nested the quotes without escaping the inner quotes. You could that like so:

```
select '(789,"(456, ""(123,blablabla)"")")'::SOME_ANOTHER_DAMNIT_TYPE;
```

i.e. by doubling the `"`.

For your case, I would suggest to avoid representing your record values as `text` only to cast them as your type later on. You can specify the record values directly, without going through `text` like so:

```
select (789,(456, (123,'blablabla')))::SOME_ANOTHER_DAMNIT_TYPE;
```